# Firefox addon for URL path sensitive password storage

Tags: firefox, password-manager

Currently Firefox (33) has an annoying limitation regarding password storage with the built-in password manager because services are only distinguished by the host part of the URL which prevents storing passwords for services running under different pathes (e.g. `example.org/myservice1` and `example.org/example2`), because one can only save one username-password-pair for the URL host `example.org` (it is possible to same multiple username-password-pairs for the host, though).

I just checked out some allround password managers, some claiming they extend the built-in pasword manager (e.g. [Master Password+](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/master-password/)), others just reinventing the wheel. It turned to a trial-error-search because no password manager mentions path specific password storage explicitly, so I'm asking for assistance.

Comment: Side note ("because one can only save one username-password-pair for the URL host"): Firefox allows to save more than one username-password pair per host (focusing the username input field gives you a list of all saved entries).

Comment: Good point, @unor, I corrected that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem sounds like it could be solved by an autofill extension. I've used [one](http://www.chromeextensions.org/utilities/autofill/#.VRPt5XXN9FQ) in Chrome for a site where Chrome just wouldn't save the username and password, which supports regexps for URLs to apply each rule; it has a [Firefox counterpart](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-262804/) but as far as I can tell the Firefox version only matches on the site name, not on the full URL, so it won't help you.

**[Autofill Forms](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autofill-forms/?src=search)**, on the other hand, allows to define profiles at least based on a prefix of the URL (and, I think, based on a regexp, but I haven't investigated that). So you could define separate profiles for the different parts of the site and record different passwords in each.

A limitation of this approach is that your password is saved in the extension's settings, not in a separate location that may be better-protected. This may or may not be ok for you depending on what synchronization you have in place for extension settings and how sensitive the password is.

Comment: The add-on website (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-262804/) states "However, the data saved by this extension is NOT encrypted". It's a bad idea to use it as a password manager, although possible.

Comment: @KarlRichter If it was encrypted, where would you store the encryption password? Whether it's suitable or not depends on the sensitivity of the password compared to other data. For example, if your home directory is encrypted as a whole, this isn't a concern.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Stupid me...

Comment: @Gilles: how do they manage to store it encrypted with the master password? Wouldn't that imply that the storage for the form data is also in some global place?

Comment: @0xc Who do you mean by "they"? What master password?

Comment: @Gilles: the authors of Autofill Forms, sorry.

Comment: @0xc They don't AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an intrinsic limitation of Firefox rather than something that can easily be solved by an add-on. Therefore
I requested that feature as https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1147651.